# Is there a way to make Perl regex searches case-insensitive?

Tags: regex, perl

Example:

```
my $cities = qr/San Francisco|Los Angeles/;
```

The scalar `$cities` will match `San Francisco` and `Los Angeles` but will not match `SAN FRANCISCO`, `LOS ANGELES`, `san francisco`, or `los angeles`.  Is there a way to make these variables case insensitive without having to create a capitalized version of them?

Comment: (It will also match `New Los Angeles`, etc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
my $cities = qr/San Fransisco|Los Angeles/i;
```

[Perl regular expression modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)

Answer (score 8):

It's not that you want to make the scalar `$cities` case-insensitive, but the regular expression it is referencing.  Use the `/i` modifier.

```
my $cities = qr/San Fransisco|Los Angeles/i;
```

You may find it useful to read the Perl regular expression tutorial: `perldoc perlretut`.